# Create Products Programatically with Custom Options

Tags: php, magento

I have Create a Module in Which ,There is a Tab in Admin of Name Create Sample Product ,when i do click on that tab ,request goes to a controller 
and it creates sample products 
this is my custom module controller code

```
public function createsamplesAction(){  
        // $rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
        $subcats = $cat->getChildren();

        foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid):

            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);

            if($_category->getName() =='T-SHIRT' || $_category->getName() =='HOODIE' || $_category->getName() =='SWEATER'):

                $categoryid[] = $_category->getId();

            endif;

        endforeach;

        $samplepro1 = 'ocodepro1'; //product name
        $samplepro2 = 'ocodepro2'; //product name
        $samplepro3 = 'ocodepro3';
        $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //getting product model
        $collection = $model->getCollection(); //products collection
    foreach ($collection as $product) //loop for getting products
    {                  

    $model->load($product->getId());
    $sku = $model->getSku(); 
       if($sku == $samplepro1 || $sku == $samplepro2 || $sku == $samplepro3)
       {
            $skuArray[]=$model->getSku();
       }              
    }
    if(!empty($skuArray)){  

        if($skuArray[0]=='ocodepro1' && $skuArray[1]=='ocodepro2' && $skuArray[2]=='ocodepro3'){
        $message =  $this->__('Error ! You have Already Created Sample Products');
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addError($message);

    }
    }

    else{
        for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

            if($i==0){  
             $product->setSku('ocodepro1');
             $product->setName('T-SHIRT');
             $product->setPrice(150);
             $product->setCategoryIds(array($categoryid[0]));

           }
           else if($i==1){  
            $product->setSku('ocodepro2');
            $product->setName('HOODIE');
            $product->setPrice(300);
            $product->setCategoryIds(array($categoryid[1]));

           }

    else if($i==2){ 
            $product->setSku('ocodepro3');
            $product->setName('SWEATER');
            $product->setPrice(300);
            $product->setCategoryIds(array($categoryid[2]));
           }

                    $product->setDescription('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap');

           $product->setShortDescription("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap");

                    //----- company address and map

                    $product->setTypeId('simple');
                    $product->setAttributeSetId(4); // need to look this up
                    //$product->setCategoryIds(array($categoryid)); // need to look these up


                    $product->setWeight(1.0);
                    $product->setTaxClassId(1); // taxable goods
                    $product->setVisibility(1); // catalog, search
                    $product->setStatus(1); // enabled
                    $productQty = '1000';
                   //$stockData=$product->getStockData();
                    $stockData['qty']=$productQty;
                    $stockData['is_in_stock']=1;
                    $stockData['manage_stock']=1;
                    $stockData['use_config_manage_stock']=0;
                    $product->setStockData($stockData);
                    $product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));


             $product->save();


            $_proid= $product->save();

            $this->_createOptions($_proid->getId());






    }  

      if($product->save()){


            $message =  $this->__('Success ! Sample Products Plans have been Created.');
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addSuccess($message);

        }


        else{

            $message =  $this->__('Error ! There was an Error Please Try Again Later.');
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addError($message);


        }

    }//

        $url= Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_product');


        $this->_redirectUrl($url);
}


protected function _createOptions($id){
         $_loadproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
         $options = array(
                    array(
                    'title' => 'Front View',
                    'type' => 'field',
                    'is_require' => 0,
                    'sort_order' => 1,
                    'is_delete' => '',
                    'previous_type' => '',
                    'previous_group' => '',
                    'price' => '0.00',
                    'price_type' => 'fixed',
                    'sku' => ''
                    ),
                    array(
                    'title' => 'Back View',
                    'type' => 'field',
                    'is_require' => 0,
                    'sort_order' => 2,
                    'is_delete' => '',
                    'previous_type' => '',
                    'previous_group' => '',
                    'price' => '0.00',
                    'price_type' => 'fixed',
                    'sku' => ''
                    ),

                    array(
                    'title' => 'Size & Quantity',
                    'type' => 'area',
                    'is_require' => 0,
                    'sort_order' => 3,
                    'is_delete' => '',
                    'previous_type' => '',
                    'previous_group' => '',
                    'price' => '0.00',
                    'price_type' => 'fixed',
                    'sku' => ''
                    ),


                    array(
                    'title' => 'Name & Number',
                    'type' => 'area',
                    'is_require' => 0,
                    'sort_order' => 4,
                    'is_delete' => '',
                    'previous_type' => '',
                    'previous_group' => '',
                    'price' => '0.00',
                    'price_type' => 'fixed',
                    'sku' => ''
                    ));

            $_loadproduct->setProductOptions($options);
            $_loadproduct->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
           $_loadproduct->save();


    }
```

and this code create products with different sku's 
but when i click on first product from product grid and check custom options. it shows four option , those i want ,but when i click on second or third product and check their custom options it shows repeated custom options 
product 2(HOODIE) show two time repeated custom options and product 3 SWEATER shows three time repeated custom option Like this
[image]

i want every custom attribute for every product only once like this.
[image]

Please Help..

Comment: do you get the repeated values for product sweater only or for all three?

Comment: i get repeated value for sweater and hoodie as well

Comment: do you get `already created sample product` error if you retry?

Comment: yes i am getting that error if  those added products aleady and i retry to add them again

Comment: try by adding `$options = array();` before the line 
`$_loadproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);` in the function `_createOptions($id)`.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `createsamplesAction()`, You are assigning `$options` variable to product.

```
$product->setProductOptions($options);
```

where is your `$options` variable.

If you have. Please declare it as array before for loop.

```
$options = array();
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    //your code here
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: It was commented code ,i removed commenting symbols by mistake now i have edited this.i am calling method _createOptions($id) and passing id in that method please take a look of whole code

Answer (score 0):

when you say the first product is fine but the second one repeats twice and third one three times, this means `$options` is building up on each cycle. I suggest you to add `$options = array();` in the `_createOptions($id)` function so it looks like:

```
protected function _createOptions($id){
     $options = array();
     $_loadproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
     ...................
     ...................
}
```

Hope this will solve the repetition issue.

Comment: did the suggestion helped you?